# Hard drive after formatting disk during installing windows

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, formatting

I wanted to replace an old windows installation with a new one. herefore, I started from a windows installation USB stick, and tried to format the disk before installing the fresh windows.
An error ocurred while formatting the disk. After that, it says that the disk has a size of 0B.

With a Linux USB stick, I also couldn't find the disk. Instead I got the following error at startup

```bsh
ata1: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
```

What can I do, to check if the disc is still alive? And can an error while formatting a disk damage it?

Comment: If you boot up off the USB device again, are you able to repeat the format? Alternatively you could use the Heron Boot CD (downloadable from a few places), or you could find a copy of fdisk.exe/.com and fdisk the drive to reset the Master Boot Record.

Comment: Try this software....http://hddguru.com/software/2005.10.02-MHDD/